# C# .dll Runs on Some Machines but not Others

Tags: compilation, nlog, ilmerge

Okay...  here is the deal (and I wish I could provide a code example, but this is a problem at the library level and not limited to a specific function/file):

I am creating a common logging dll to be used throughout all applications in my organization.  As part of the logger, we are using a logging framework names '**NLog**.'  The .dll project has several projects and is merged into one .dll using '**ILMerge**.'  I, of course, compile it on my machine and make the .dll and relevant configurations available to the other application(s) that will be using it.  When the .dll is used in another application, it runs just fine on my machine and on almost every other machine that is being used in my organization.  However, on one of the other developer's machines, the .dll does not work correctly.  The only way that I have been able to get it to work correctly on his machine is to actually re-compile the .dll on his machine.

Has anyone else encountered this problem?  I have written like a billion .dll's and have **NEVER** encountered this issue.

Thank you for helping!  If you need more information, let me know.

Brett

Comment: did you try registering it with Windows? There may be a conflicting DLL there. Also clear out your developers caches, the library could be caching.

Answer (score 0):

Are all dependent libraries having exactly the same versions on your machine and on your colleagues machine? Sounds like a version conflict.